# How execute multiple methods using transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am facing an issue.I am working on a peace of code where several methods are called from within main method.I am using net.sf.ehcache.TransactionController class to begin, commit and rollback local transactions which apply on the main method only.Now the problem is that because several method are executing within a single transaction it locks the required tables for a long period of time and the other transactions would have to wait to release the lock which causes to decrease the performance of the application.Second, instead of single transaction if I apply nested transaction at methods level, it resolve the problem but then the data became inconsistent.so what would be the best transaction approach I can choose so that lock will not affect the application performance and data will also remain consistent.